What is the fallacy of excluding counterexamples?
What is the fallacy of making up new categories so as to exclude counterexamples which falsify the rule?
Thank you for any example from the academic literature.

Lakatos called this "monster-barring".

The whole machinery of sigma-algebras was developed to monster-bar the phenomenon of nonmeasurable sets.  One would have naively expected to be able to assign a reasonable measure to every set.  This is indeed possible if one sticks with ZF+(dependent choice), namely in the Solovay model.  But generally dependent choice is not enough to some some important pieces of mathematics, such as the Hahn-Banach theorem.  At this point one has no choice but forego the totality of the measure, and reconcile oneself to working in a sigma-algebra of measurable sets.

One-line description is too vague to tell what you have in mind, could you give examples? Sharpening distinctions to pin down precise conditions under which a rule applies seems like sound methodology rather than a fallacy.

It might help to ward off future VTCs with a simple example. The question on it's face is an important question.

I want to say "Outlier removal"...

When deployed improperly, this is the informal fallacy, "no true Scotsman":

one modifies a prior claim in response to a counterexample by asserting the counterexample is excluded by definition.

The original category gets modified by a term like "real," "true," etc.
Of course, refinement and subdivision of categories over time can also be an acceptable means of organizing entities. This is the basis behind morphological classification of species.

+1 The OP should be aware that as Conifold notes, there's a distinction between the abusive practice of the NTS where the exclusion is unjustified, and a substantive attempt to make a definition more precise by excluding poor counterexamples.

It's not a fallacy at all, and you can't get by without it. It's fixing a problem in the definition or communication of a concept.
Alice: "The English word colour has a letter u."
Bob: "Well, Americans..."
Alice: "Oops, you're right: the British English word colour has a letter u."
or:
"Oh, I meant English as in belonging to England not English as in the language English."
or even:
"Silence, colonial scum! Filthy Americans aren't true English speakers! Speaking English means speaking it the way they speak it in England, and in England it has a letter u."
All perfectly fine (rationally speaking). Alice is just clarifying what she meant.
No True Scotsman is carrying on against the evidence as if the initial claim did not need modification, while in fact modifying the initial claim. It is a kind of dishonest (or self-deluding) rhetorical tactic. It's an informal fallacy if the speaker accidentally tricks himself into thinking that the initial claim really didn't need modification or clarification.
As with all informal fallacies, the only use for its name, ever is as an indexing point to help yourself avoid making certain cognitive errors in your own internal reasoning. This error in particular is usually trivially averted in actual conversation.

Useless:
Alice: "X is like this."
Bob: "Y is not like this and is called an X."
Alice: "Y is not a true X."
Bob: "NO TRUE SCOTSMAN!"
Alice: "STYLE OVER SUBSTANCE!"
Bob: "EXPELI ARMUS!"
Alice: "AVADA KEDAVRA!"

Useful:
Alice: "X is like this."
Bob: "Y is not like this and Y is an X."
Alice: "Y is not a true X."
Bob: "Okay, what is your definition of a true X and a false X?"
Alice: "A true X is [whatever]."
Bob: "I was talking about X meaning [whatever else]."

is this subtly different from the examples in the wikipedia article, where “A true X is an X that is like this” which may be paired with other information regarding X (such that sugar need not be offered at breakfast in Scotland) and involve further fallacy?

@fuzzyTew maybe. For Alice to be doing an informal fallacy, Alice has to be wrong about something or trying to make Bob wrong about something. You can be wrong about facts about definitions (i.e. whether they comport with common use) but definitions can't be wrong.

Try inverting whose definition comports with common use. Suddenly Alice is the reasonable one and Bob is cracking a dad joke. [A: no cat can drink 60 gallons of gasoline every day for a week. B: my Snowcat all terrain vehicle sure can. A: no real cat...]

@gs: For this answer's context, "Y is an X" is assumed to be an agreed upon truth. Your dad joke example subverts this assumption, B does not genuinely believe that A was referring to any word ending in "cat". Not that comical subversion isn't a thing in real life, but it's not really part of what this answer is trying to address.

The phenomenon you mentioned is rather common in Academia.  Lakatos in his book Proofs and Refutations referred to it as "monster-barring".  There is a considerable literature discussing this; see e.g.,

Leopold Karl.

Here is a pair of examples:

The whole machinery of sigma-algebras was developed to monster-bar the phenomenon of nonmeasurable sets. One would have naively expected to be able to assign a reasonable (Lebesgue) measure to every set.  This is indeed possible if one sticks with ZF+(dependent choice), namely in the Solovay model. But generally dependent choice is not enough to some some important pieces of mathematics, such as the Hahn-Banach theorem. At this point one has no choice but to forego the totality of the measure, and reconcile oneself to working in a sigma-algebra of measurable sets.

Cauchy published a sum theorem in 1821 that amounts to the claim that a convergent series of continuous functions has a continuous sum.  This is often reported in the literature as "Cauchy's mistake".  However, in 1853 Cauchy modified the hypothesis of the theorem by including a "monster-barring" condition that is difficult to understand from the viewpoint of non-infinitesimal analysis.  It is easier to understand from the viewpoint of infinitesimal analysis; see e.g.,



Bascelli, T.; Błaszczyk, P.; Borovik, A.; Kanovei, V.; Katz, K.; Katz, M.; Kutateladze, S.; McGaffey, T.; Schaps, D.; Sherry, D. "Cauchy's infinitesimals, his sum theorem, and foundational paradigms." Foundations of Science 23 (2018), no. 2, 267-296. https://doi.org/10.1007/s10699-017-9534-y, https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.07723, https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=3803893


Strengthening the antecedent of a theorem in order to make it actually true, does seem to fit the behaviour described in the OP, but it should surely not be called a fallacy.

@kaya3, sometimes adding such hypotheses seems haphazard (and therefore "monster-barring") because the phenomenon under investigation has not been properly understood yet.  For example, even though Cauchy seems to have patched up the result, it does not clearly emerge that he understood the difference between two types of convergence of series that we speak of today, namely pointwise convergence and uniform convergence.

As other answers have pointed out, this is often not a fallacy and can be done appropriately and in good faith. It is sometimes referred to as "monster barring", but that is a valid technique that shows up often in math and sometimes in science. When done in bad faith and in a particular way though, it can result in the "No True Scotsman" fallacy which is well discussed in other answers.
I am providing a separate answer because I suspect you may be thinking of the informal fallacy of moving the goalpost. Moving the goalpost usually manifests as rejecting some form of evidence, including counterexamples, and demanding additional evidence, usually after it was at least reasonably believed that everyone had agreed on what type of evidence would be necessary. This is not a formal fallacy, but it is an informal one that appears frequently in politics and in discussions about conspiracy theories. Snopes has a rather good writeup of it at https://www.snopes.com/articles/464308/logical-fallacies-and-moving-goalposts/

I'm in the "not necessarily a fallacy" camp, as this move can be quite fruitful.

All numbers can be expressed as ratios of integers (Pythagoras or someone).
The square root of 2 cannot be expressed as ratios of integers (Hippasus of Metapontum or someone).
The square root of 2 is not a rational number.

This could have been a "no true Scotsman", but instead led to several centuries of fruitful work by Dedekind, Cantor, etc.

My hunches, if they mean anything at all:

Cherry-picking/Confirmation bias (ignoring counter examples)

Self-sealing argument (making ad hoc adjustments to a hypothesis so as to fit the facts, which isn't really bad if you consider the converse)


In sum, unfalsifiability and hence verging on or is pseudoscience (per Karl Popper)
